# Altium: how to explode an imported 3D model

Tags: pcb, altium, model, 3d

I've imported a 3D model of an enclosure and I want to check if my PCB will fit inside the box but I can't "open" the box inside Altium. How can I explode or take a 3D model apart in Altium?

Comment: Typically I do it the other way around. I export my board to my CAD software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be much better off using a tool like SolidWorks or SolidEdge to do your mechanical work. Altium is not designed to handle enclosures. You would export your board from Altium as a STEP model and open it in the mechanical CAD software. If you use SolidWorks, you would use the built-in tools to separate the pieces of the step model, and you would put your board STEP model into it. You should not be doing this in Altium.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two bodys for your enclousure. One should be the enclousure itself, the other one being the lid of such a enclousure.

Now you match your PCB inside the enclousure and then place the lid over it. Thats the only way that I'm aware of doing such thing in Altium.